# Whole HTML page does not show up in a WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have an HTML page opened in a WebView in my Android app. But that page is not auto-sized to fit in the WebView, hence some part of the page does not show up there in the WebView. I want that, when an HTML page is opened in a WebView, the whole page must fit in the WebView. I have gone through other related questions and I have tried them, but it did not work for me.
I have added these lines to WebView:

```
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

but nothing happened, is there any other way of implementing this thing? Help is always appreciated.

Comment: did you code your html page by Using HTML 5 ??

Comment: @Houcine yes, the page is HTML 5, Now whats the issue if you can explain or suggest a solution ..????

Answer (score 3):

This works with me:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

myWebView.loadUrl("http://saudi-arabia.gold-price-today.com/");
```

If this code doesn't work for you, try to use it in new project.